# Como deixar o background de um texto do tamanho do texto e não do parágrafo?

Tags: css3

Como faço para o **background-color** do **`h4`** ficar apenas da largura do texto. Não posso delimitar uma largura fixa pq não sei o tamanho do texto e também não posso utilizar **display:inline-block** pq preciso dos **h4** um embaixo dos outro. Alguém sabe como posso fazer isto ou alguma outra solução para o caso será bem-vinda!

```css
h1{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1>Testando!</h1>
```

O que consegui até agora não é o resultado esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: as tags de título h1,h2, etc ocupam a linha toda, então o comportamento está certo. Para ter um background apenas no texto precisa usar outro elemento, por exemplo por o texto num `label` ou `span`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se os seus H4 estiverem dentro de um *container* vc pode usar `flexbox` para atingir seu objetivo.

Primeiro vc determina que no seu *container* os itens vão se alinha como colunas, um embaixo do outro `flex-direction: column;` depois que eles vão ficar a esquerda para evitar que ocupem a linha inteira `align-items: flex-start;`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
h1{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Testando!</h1>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h1>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem, ipsum.</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Blza Hugo, estou utilizando **Vue** e o **Vuetify** que é uma espécie de Bootstrap do Vue, aí ele já vem com o sistema de grid que usa um flex próprio. Fiquei meio com o pé atrás de aplicar flexbox, mas, acho que terá que ser assim mesmo. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @LeAndrade uai jovem, se vc está usando o BS4 o grid todo dele já é em flex, e ele tem classes nativas de flex como vc pode consultar aqui: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/ não tem pq não usar flex nessa caso! Sucesso ai!

Comment: Nao, não Hugo. Estou utilizando **Vuetify** que é um framework CSS específico pra **Vue.js**, que tbm tem um sistema de grid com classes flex. Não tem nada a ver com o Bootstrap não.

Comment: @LeAndrade ah tá, viajei aqui rss, de qq forma se faz parte do framework manda ver nesse Flex ai :)